# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) - KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access, segmentation-fault

I have uploaded the app and it get rejected saying

**We found that your app crashed on iPad running iOS 7, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.**

Well the time when I uploaded, iOS7 was not launched.

The crash report says

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xb1b1f20b

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a2f5b26 objc_msgSend + 6
1   MapKit                          0x30ca46a6 -[MKMapView mapViewDidFinishLoadingTiles:] + 46
2   VectorKit                       0x376bbaf4 -[VKTileSource didFinishWithNetwork] + 68
3   VectorKit                       0x376bc196 __32-[VKTileSource performDownload:]_block_invoke126 + 38
4   GeoServices                     0x345b6fdc ___ZNK49-[GEOTileLoaderInternal _loadedTile:forKey:info:]66__49-[GEOTileLoaderInternal _loadedTile:forKey:info:]_block_invoke3$_1clERKN8LoadItem9RequesterE_block_invoke_2 + 52
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7ddd78 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7ddd64 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7e47bc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 264
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2fab881c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2fab70f0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1296
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2fa21ce2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2fa21ac6 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
12  GraphicsServices                0x3471c27e GSEventRunModal + 134
13  UIKit                           0x322c3a3c UIApplicationMain + 1132
```

In crash we see `MapKit                         0x30ca46a6 -[MKMapView mapViewDidFinishLoadingTiles:]`.

Is MapKit is giving problem?

For mapkit, below is what I have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Location";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D cords = {29.32511601390379, 48.08847418705136};
    MKCoordinateSpan span = {0.008400,0.008400};
    region = (MKCoordinateRegion) {cords,span};
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];

    DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
}
```

Also I don't have dealloc in mapkitviewcontroller. Is that fine? I am asking as this error is related to memory management.

My App was having 5 tabs. First 4 tabs are just UIWebView. For webview, I found that I didn't put webview in dealloc. Below is what I had in webview,

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Right now I don't have iOS 7 on my xcode too. I need to download that, but thought to ask before here.

**Note:** All is working perfectly with iOS 6.

Any guesses why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I put `mapView` in dealloc, the problem get solved.

On further investigation, also noticed that I didn't added title for `DisplayMap`.

```
DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
ann.title = @"My Location";
```

Comment: did you explicitly nil it out? I'm having the same issue, seeing crash in a Crittercism report, but unable to reproduce it myself

Comment: @HenrikHartz : earlier I had `ann.title = @""`

Comment: @HenrikHartz did you find the cause? i'm seeing same issue in a Crashlytics report, but unable to reproduce it myself

Comment: @Chris no I have not been able to reproduce this issue

Answer (score 4):

Did set the map view delegate to nil before navigating away from the page. Also I think there is some memory management issue with IOS maps. So It is better to release maps in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: I resolved the issue by setting the map view delegate to nil inside my delegate's dealloc method.  It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me as Apple's implementation of MKMapView should maintain a weak reference to the delegate.  But who knows, maybe there is some buggy code in the iOS 7 MKMapView implementation.